# How to show error messages for multiple radio buttons at once

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

If I click the 'next' button on my page it is validating the inputs. If I do it this way, only radio button 1 is shown as a required radio. I need to show an error even for radio button 2.

```js
function nextBtn() {
  if (!document.getElementById('Radio1').checked && !document.getElementById('Radio2').checked) {
    document.getElementById('Radio1').required = true;
    document.getElementById('Radio2').required = true;
    document.getElementById('nextbutton').type = "submit";
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" id="Radio1" name="radios">
  <input type="radio" id="Radio2" name="radios">
  <button id="nextbutton" onclick="nextBtn()">Next</button>
</form>
```

Comment: As you're using the standard HTML validation notifications, then this is not possible. It only ever shows the first validation failure, not all of them. However, in this case I'd say that makes the most sense. Your error says 'Please select one of these options' which is a valid instruction and makes sense that it only appears once. Showing it twice would just confuse users.

Comment: I need to highlight both the radios that's my requirement, I have a separate custom error message and I am hiding the default one.

Comment: In that case you will need to use a third party library to handle your validation. Also, for future reference, it's always best to include *all* relevant details in the question